# Const variable changed with pointer in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants

The variable `i` is declared const but still I am able to change the value with a pointer to the memory location to it. How is it possible?

```
int main()
{

    const int i = 11;
    int *ip = &i;
    *ip=100;
    printf("%d\n",*ip);
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

When I compile, I get this warning :

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

Output is this

```
100
100
```

Comment: You're discarding the const qualifer, consult your compiler documentation if you want warnings to be errors.

Answer (score 9):

The `const` is not a request to the compiler to make it impossible to change that variable.  Rather, it is a *promise* to the compiler that you won't.  If you break your promise, your program is allowed to do anything at all, including crash.

For example, if I compile your example code using gcc with the `-O2` optimisation level, the output is:

```
100
11
```

The compiler is *allowed* to place a `const` qualified variable in read-only memory, but it doesn't *have* to (apart from anything else, some environments don't implement any such thing).  In particular, it is almost always impractical for automatic ("local") variables to be placed in read-only memory.

If you change the declaration of of `i` to:

```
static const int i = 11;
```

then you may well find that the program now crashes at runtime.

Comment: It's not actually the `static` which crashes the program. It's the incorrect cast. That's the bug, and the precise consequences of a bug can depend on many minute factors such as this one `static`. And on another compiler, you may see the crash only if there is _no_ `static`; the result of a bug is hard to predict.

Comment: It's not actually the cast the crashes the program - the cast is allowed, if somewhat dubious.  It's modifying the object that was declared with a `const` qualifier that's the bug.

Comment: `static` _is_ related to the crash. In modern systems, `static const` variables (or `const` variables at file scope) can be allocated on a read-only segment, and attempting to write to such an address will cause a protection fault.

Answer (score 8):

`const` is a *compile-time* feature.
It doesn't prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot; that's what the warning is for.

Comment: `const` is not necessarily only a compile-time feature.  In my environment, if I make the variable `i` in the above example `static`, then the program crashes at runtime.

Comment: There is a difference between const and static. const allows the compiler to generate warnings. static allows the compiler to replace the value with a literal number or place it in read only memory or anything else it likes

Comment: @Martin Beckett: `static` alone does not allow the compiler to place it in read-only memory - in principle it is only `const` that allows that, but in practice `const` must be combined with `static` for this effect because it is simply impractical to do so for automatic variables.  `const` alone variables can be replaced by literals at their point of use, even automatic ones.

Answer (score 3):

Though it may be a warning in C, this is a compiler error in C++.

If you somehow manage to cast this `const int` in C/C++, then it may result in **undefined behavior**. The reason is, you are casting a number literal (i.e. `const int i =`**11**`;`) from `const` to a mutable value.

There is difference between what your code shows and following sequence:

```
int x = 11;    // x is modifiable
const int i = x;
int *ip = (int*)(&i);  // ok
*ip=100;
```

Comment: Whether it's a warning or an error depends on the flexibility of the compiler, not the language. It's wrong in both C and C++.

Comment: @ChrisLutz, for C it might be dependable (that's why I used "may be"), however, for C++ it should definitely be a compiler error, because of breaking `const` correctness.

Answer (score 2):

A `const`-qualified object cannot be modified. If such an attempt is made, the program exhibits undefined behavior (C99 6.7.3.5). (Your program is incorrect.)

More on `const`: an object which is *not* declared as `const` *can* be modified, but not by the use of `const`-qualified lvalues. This is most evident when pointers are involved. For example, consider the declarations:

```
int i = 10;
int *p1 = &i;
const int *p2 = &i;
```

It is possible to modify `i` through `i` itself and through `p1`, but not through `p2`. This means that `*p2` can evaluate to different values, even though `p2` points to a `const` object, because *other* statements may change the object pointed to by `p2` (an aliasing pointer, as in the example).

However, if `i` itself was `const`-qualified, then attempting to modify it through `p1` will yield undefined behavior (as your code does).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the attempt to modify `i` that causes your program's behavior to be undefined, it's the initialization of `ip`.

```
const int i = 11;
int *ip = &i;
```

`&i` is of type `const int*`.  `ip` is of type `int*`.  Attempting to initialize an `int*` with a `const int*` value is a *constraint violation*.  A conforming implementation is requires to issue a diagnostic; once it's done that, it may or may not reject the translation unit.  If it accepts it, the C standard says nothing about the resulting program's behavior.

Compilers that accept such things typically generate code equivalent to a conversion from `const int*` to `int*`, making the declaration effectively equivalent to:

```
int *ip = (int*)&i;
```

but the language doesn't require this behavior.

**Don't ignore warnings.**

(Note that with the cast, the code doesn't violate a constraint; then the behavior of the following

```
*ip = 100;
```

is undefined because it attempts to modify a `const`-qualified object.)

gcc in particular has a lot of cases where diagnostics for constraint violations are handled (by default) as warnings rather than fatal errors.  I personally dislike that about gcc; it lets through too much bad code.

(Your program's behavior is also undefined because you call `printf` without a visible declaration; add `#include <stdio.h>`.  And `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.)