# const variable value is changed by using a pointer

Tags: c

The output of the following program is 50 on gcc.
How is it possible as x is constant variable and *p is x itself as p is a constant pointer pointing to value at x. 
Where as turbo c gives compiler error.
Is it an undefined behaviour? please explain.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int x = 25;
    int * const p = &x;
    *p = 2 * x;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you do so, its Undefined behaviour.

Comment: ur compiler shouldn't allow that, not allowed to convert from `const int*` to `int* const`: http://ideone.com/AnuWLM

Comment: Removed C++ tag: this will not compile as C++. A C compiler will probably emit a scary warning.

Comment: Compiler could allow it because it can't know that in any xase

Comment: ***int*** `main()`...

Comment: "Is it an undefined behaviour?" - Sure, because it's a constraint violation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [constants and pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945640/constants-and-pointers-in-c)

Comment: i executed on compileonline.com and got 50 as ouput which is a gcc compiler

Comment: @Krishna did gcc not worn about the bad pointer assingment `p=&x`?

Comment: I believe @H2CO3 has a trigger to fire every time someone posts code with `main` function declared as `void` and/or written without `return` statement. :)

Comment: @NemanjaBoric True dat!

Comment: Did you compile with gcc with all the warnings turned on?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric `main` doesn't need return statement

Comment: this has been asked many times before, please check SO before asking. possible duplicate of [Const variable changed with pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371892/const-variable-changed-with-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @Kal It doesn't, technically (not in C99 and C++, at least), but as I've explained it yesterday, it's horrible style to omit the `return`. But I don't want to get into the non-constructive flamewar again, so let's not discuss this topic.

Comment: I am just referring yesterday's discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402853/must-the-int-main-function-return-a-value-in-all-compilers/18402896#comment27029402_18402896

Comment: @H2CO3 can you link to the flamewar? i have not seen it

Comment: @Kal [Here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402853/must-the-int-main-function-return-a-value-in-all-compilers/18402896#comment27029221_18402896).

Comment: @H2CO3 do you think every `void` function needs a `return;` at the end?

Comment: @Kal No, I don't. That's because `void` means "return no value", and "return upon reaching end-of-function" is intuitive. "return 0 implicitly" isn't.

Comment: @Krishna Kittu have you any additions to your Question, or want to know something additional to satisfy you with an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to change it but the behavior is undefined, as its mentioned in the standard!

Its in c11 under 6.7.3

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Standard quotation == automatic +1.

Answer (score 3):

```
int * const p=&x;
```

This is not a valid program. `&x` is of type `const int *` but you are assigning the pointer value to an object of type `int * const`: the compiler has to issue a warning and is allowed to stop compilation.