# Why simple program for printing out dividers of the input number stopped working?

Tags: c++, c++11

here is the code I am having an issue with:

```
int printDividers(int x)
{
    for (int j=0; j<x+1; j++)
    {
        if (x%j==0) cout << j << ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int z;
    cout << "Enter a number and the program will print out it's dividors:" << endl;
    cin >> z;
    printDividers(z);

    return 0;
}
```

After entering your number it says main.exe stopped working. I haven't figured out why, I can't spot the error in the code.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Could you give an example of the input that you used to get this issue?

Comment: What is `x % 0` ?

Comment: I wonder if code compiles since `int printDividers(int x)` doesn't returns anything

Comment: @JohnOdom I am using CodeBlocks and it says there are no errors. It always crashes, no matter which number you enter. For example 5, or 53, or 7546... Nothing works.

Comment: You need to return something from your function or make it `void`.

Comment: @MathewsMathai That is normal from `main`, indicating successful completion of the program.

Comment: Some errors, like the one pointed out by CompuChip, are only exposed at runtime

Comment: Has it stoped working, or was it just never working at all? *philosophical*

Comment: @NathanOliver could you give me an example of what could I return in this function and how should I change the main program so it would work the same?

Comment: @Zaibis it stopped working after I entered an integer.

Comment: @coincoin I am new to programming and that's why this my seem dumb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `x % 0`? (Answer: *Undefined Behaviour*) This is what causes your run-time error.

Change to this:

```
for (int j=1; j<x+1; j++)
```

http://ideone.com/K5vSxt

Answer (score 4):

When `i==0`, we will run the test `if (x%0 == 0)` which isn't a valid statement because it attempt to divide by 0. Hence, your program <del>will</del> might crash. Its behavior is undefined

Comment: *Might* crash. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I edited. I'm using my mobile, so, I don't have the standard to reference

Comment: @Danh I changed the stil of your change. I hope thats what you tryed to achieve.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want to change

Answer (score 4):

You're out of luck, you are attempting to compute `% 0` in your `for` loop. Along with integral division by zero, the behaviour on doing this is *undefined*:

The C++03 Standard states in §5.6/4,

> [...] If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is
>   undefined; [...]

Comment: To quote HACK3R's(?) comment who sadly is not registred here anymore: [Standard quotation == automatic +1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18416748/2003898)

Comment: So dividing by zero is a no-go. Thank you!

Comment: Only for integral types. Floating point division by zero *is* defined. But I'd still advise against it.