# Able to change value of const in C, but not in C++

Tags: c++, c, optimization, constants

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   const int a = 2;
   long p = (long)&a;
   int *c = (int *)p;
   *c =3;
   printf("%d", a);
}
```

This code can change the value to a in C but not in  C++. I understand that C++ is applying optimization and replacing instances of `a` with `2`. So was this a bug fix in C++ or was the bug fixed by chance due to optimization?

Comment: In C++ (and most likely in C too), this is undefined behaviour. You could actually succeed in changing the value of a `const` object. So whatever you see can be considered to be "chance" (of course, looking at the assembly will tell you what is going on with your particular platform and compiler options.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Const variable changed with pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371892/const-variable-changed-with-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to modify a `const` value no matter directly or indirectly. This may compile in C and may even run without problem on your machine, but it's still undefined behavior.

The difference between C and C++ on this is: with `const int a = 2`, C++ treats `a` as a constant expression, for instance, you can use `a` as array dimension:

```
int n[a];  //fine in C++
```

But in C, `a` is not a constant expression, with the same code:

```
int n[a];  //VLA in C99
```

Here `n` is not a fixed-sized array, but a variable length array.

Answer (score 6):

**This is not a C vs C++ issue.** By modifying a `const` value (as well as by double-casting a pointer via a `long`), you enter the realm of [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in both languages. Therefore the difference is simply a matter of how the undefined behaviour chooses to manifest itself.

Comment: Since the behaviour is undefined, can we expect different outputs if we compile and run the same program multiple times?

Comment: @user1173339: That too would be a valid manifestation of undefined behaviour. Of course, you cannot necessarily *expect* it to happen: always printing out the word `bananas` would be just as valid a manifestation, as would be any other behaviour (crashing, tweeting on your behalf, all of the above, nothing at all, etc).

Comment: But is it not compiler specific?

Comment: @Ankur: It is in the sense that it can vary depending on the compiler. However, it can equally well vary depending on the OS, the hardware, the time of day, the alignment of stars or pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting away the constness out of `&a` and modifying the pointed value, which is undefined behavior both in C and in C++ (the trip through `long` just adds some more gratuitous UB). In C++ your compiler happens to optimize more aggressively the constant, but the point of the situation is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Your code generates undefined behavior on C++ since you're accessing memory you shouldn't

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
   const int a = 2;
   printf("%x != %x !!", sizeof(long), sizeof(void*)); // on a x64 system 4 != 8
   long p = (long)&a;
   int *c = (int *)p;
   *c =3;
   printf("%d", a);
}
```

and even if it works on a 32 bit system modifying `const` memory by casting away the constness is undefined behavior in **both** languages.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the assembly code generated by g++. The compiler statically use "$2" instead of "a", but in case of gcc it doesn't perform any static optimization. I guess there shouldn't be any undefined behaviour.

```
    .Ltext0:
                    .section    .rodata

                .LC0:
0000 256400         .string "%d"
                    .text
                    .globl  main
                main:

                .LFB0:

                    .cfi_startproc
                    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
                    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA0
0000 55             pushq   %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
0001 4889E5         movq    %rsp, %rbp
                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
0004 4883EC20       subq    $32, %rsp

                .LBB2:

0008 C745EC02       movl    $2, -20(%rbp)
     000000

000f 488D45EC       leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax
0013 488945F0       movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)

0017 488B45F0       movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
001b 488945F8       movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)

001f 488B45F8       movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
0023 C7000300       movl    $3, (%rax)
     0000

0029 488B45F8       movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
002d 8B00           movl    (%rax), %eax
002f 89C6           movl    %eax, %esi
0031 BF000000       movl    $.LC0, %edi
     00
0036 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00

                .LEHB0:

003b E8000000       call    printf
     00

0040 BE020000       movl    $2, %esi
     00
0045 BF000000       movl    $.LC0, %edi
     00
004a B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
004f E8000000       call    printf
     00

                .LEHE0:

0054 B8000000       movl    $0, %eax
     00
0059 EB08           jmp .L5

                .L4:

005b 4889C7         movq    %rax, %rdi

                .LEHB1:

005e E8000000       call    _Unwind_Resume
     00

                .LEHE1:

                .L5:

                .LBE2:

0063 C9             leave
                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
0064 C3             ret
                    .cfi_endproc

                .LFE0:

                    .globl  __gxx_personality_v0
                    .section    .gcc_except_table,"a",@progbits

                .LLSDA0:

0000 FF             .byte   0xff
0001 FF             .byte   0xff
0002 01             .byte   0x1
0003 08             .uleb128 .LLSDACSE0-.LLSDACSB0

                .LLSDACSB0:

0004 3B             .uleb128 .LEHB0-.LFB0
0005 19             .uleb128 .LEHE0-.LEHB0
0006 5B             .uleb128 .L4-.LFB0
0007 00             .uleb128 0
0008 5E             .uleb128 .LEHB1-.LFB0
0009 05             .uleb128 .LEHE1-.LEHB1
000a 00             .uleb128 0
000b 00             .uleb128 0

                .LLSDACSE0:

                    .text

                .Letext0:
```

Comment: Bad guess. Undefined behavior is not a matter of what a particular compiler does, but what behavior one can expect from *any* compiler.